# How to change Content-Type in Flurl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, content-type, asp.net-core-webapi, flurl

I have a .NET Core 2.0 WebApi application in which I have added the "Flurl.Http" (Version 2.1.0) NuGet package to my project.

I am trying to use Flurl to make a simple REST API call to one of Visual Studio Team Services' (VSTS) Api endpoints.

However, the particular VSTS api endpoint that I am calling requires that the Content-Type be set to "application/json-patch+json" instead of the typical "application/json".

In my Flurl call, I am using the "WithHeader()" method to try and set the Content-Type in the header of the request, but it is not working. Flurl seems to not allow me to override the default or standard Content-Type that is built into the PostJsonAsync method.

Does anyone know how to change the Content-Type of the request using Flurl? Or how to properly override the default behavior of the Content-Type in the Flurl configuration?

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
public bool CreateNewBug(NewBugRequest newBugRequest)
{
    return _apiUrlToCreateNewBug.WithHeader("Authorization", "Basic Base64PersonalAccessTokenGoesHere")
                                .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json-patch+json")
                                .PostJsonAsync(newBugRequest.Fields)
                                .Result
                                .IsSuccessStatusCode;
}
```

*(This code works, but the response from the VSTS api is that the Content-Type is not allowed and needs to be changed to "application/json-patch+json", which is what I tried to set it to in the header.)*

Comment: Please take a minute and read [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to avoid people skip over your questions when you stuff it with tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATE: The bug is fixed as of Flurl.Http 2.3.1, so this work-around is no longer necessary.***

The short answer is I think you've discovered a bug. `PostJsonAsync` does set the Content-Type header, but I think it should leave it alone if you've already set it yourself. If you could report it [here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/new) I should be able to get it fixed for the next release.

The work-around is fairly straightforward. You just need to take a couple extra steps to build the content and then post it using `PostAsync` instead of `PostJsonAsync`.

```
var json = FlurlHttp.GlobalSettings.JsonSerializer.Serialize(newBugRequest.Fields);
var content = new CapturedStringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

return _apiUrlToCreateNewBug
    .WithHeader("Authorization", "Basic Base64PersonalAccessTokenGoesHere")
    .PostAsync(content);
```

If you need to do this a lot, you could wrap it up in an extension method (`PostJsonPatchAsync` or similar) so you can call it fluently. See [here](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/extensibility/) for the correct way to do that.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up doing something very similar and was able to figure it out. I will post what I did shortly, as an answer to my own question.

Comment: I created an issue for this https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/256

Answer (score 5):

New answer: **Upgrade to the latest Flurl.Http**. The [issue](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/256) has been fixed in 2.3.1, so the code posted in the question (the cleanest approach) should actually work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out and find a working solution to my problem.

Here is the updated version of my working code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage CreateNewBug(NewBugRequest newBugRequest)
{
    return _apiUrlToCreateNewBug.AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                                .WithBasicAuth("", _personalAccessTokenForBasicAuth)
                                .PostAsync(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newBugRequest.Fields), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json"))
                                .Result;
}
```

The PostAsync method takes in an HttpContent object. HttpContent is an abstract class. Once I figured out all the concrete classes that implement the abstract class HttpContent, then I chose the one that best fit my situation and plugged it into the PostAsync method.

In this case, the StringContent class was the one that best fit what I needed. One of StringContent's constructors takes in the Content-Type as one of its parameters. So I passed in my custom Content-Type and everything worked as expected.

Comment: That's more or less the same solution. The main difference is that mine uses Flurl objects `CapturedStringContent`, which allows better diagnostics from `FlurlHttpException` because you have access to the request body, and `GlobalSettings`, just in case you made any tweaks to the default JSON searializer.